# Dyamic double arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to use malloc to create an array I keep getting this error.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning C4047   '=': 'DynamicArray *' differs in levels of indirection from 'double **' cStudy      19

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning C4133   'initializing': incompatible types - from 'int *' to 'double *' cStudy      36

```
 typedef struct
{
double *arrayPointer;
int effectiveSize;
int maximumSize;
} DynamicArray;

void CreateArray(DynamicArray *mArray, int initialSize)
{ 
//TODO: Use malloc to create an array of the initial size.  Assign to   the arrayPointer variable

//TODO: Set effective size to 0 and maximum size to the initial size
mArray->arrayPointer = malloc(initialSize *sizeof(double));
mArray->effectiveSize = 0;
mArray->maximumSize = initialSize;
}
```

void ExpandArray(DynamicArray *mArray, int newSize)
{

```
    double* newArray;

    mArray->arrayPointer = newArray = (int *)malloc(newSize * sizeof(double));
    memcpy(newArray, &mArray[mArray->effectiveSize], mArray->effectiveSize * sizeof(double));


    free(mArray->arrayPointer);
    //mArray->effectiveSize = 0;
    mArray->maximumSize = newSize;
```

}

Updated code but expand does not work.

Comment: You may want to look at `calloc` instead of `malloc` when allocating numeric arrays (or pointers to numeric arrays) as it will initialize all elements to zero (or `NULL` in the pointer case). This will prevent the accidental attempt to read from an uninitialized element.

Answer (score 2):

This assignment

```
mArray = (double *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(double *));
```

should be

```
mArray->arrayPointer = malloc(initialSize * sizeof(double));
```

Several changes are required:

- `sizeof` should be of `double`, not `double*`
- The assignment should be to `mArray->arrayPointer`, not to `mArray` itself.
- No cast to `double*` is necessary in C.

The point about casting applies to this line as well:

```
double* newArray = (int *)malloc(newSize * sizeof(double));
```

Note, however, that `ExpandArray` would likely use [`realloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html), not the plain `malloc`.

Comment: That fixed it thanks very much , am I doing the expand part right ? I know its not finished but am I on the right track?

Comment: @rev2k9 Your approach will work, but `realloc` would allocate and copy in a single call. You would be better off wrapping `realloc`.

Comment: Teacher does not want me to do things the smart way... I need to copy the data he said do memcpy or for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out :D

```
double * newArray = malloc(sizeof(double)* newSize);
memcpy(newArray, mArray->arrayPointer, newSize * sizeof *newArray);
free(mArray->arrayPointer);
mArray->maximumSize = newSize;
mArray->arrayPointer = newArray;
```

I just need more cofeee.